# Is it possible to get the filename of the failed test in the _failed() hook?

Tags: codeception

If I am able to get the filename of the failed test, I could run the test a second time to check if it really is a error or just a coincidence. Until now I couldnt find a sulution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the instance of test in _failed hook, so you can do the same thing as [RunFailed extension](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/4.1/ext/RunFailed.php#L62-L67):

```
use Codeception\Test\Descriptor;

public function _failed(\Codeception\TestInterface $test, $fail)
{
    $fullName = Descriptor::getTestFullName($test);
}
```

Original answer:

Codeception has [RunFailed extension](https://codeception.com/extensions#RunFailed), which is enabled by default.

It saves the names of all failed tests to `tests/_output/failed` file, and failed tests can be executed by running `codecept run -g failed` command.

In order to make CI pass if failed tests pass on second run you can use this command:
`codecept run || codecept run -g failed`

Comment: Thanks, but its not what I need. I want to generate a shell command with the test name and file name. Right now a mail is generated after each failed test, but I want the mail to be generated only if the test failed a second time. It would be easy with the file name of the test.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Now I have a last problem, how can I get the environment name?

Comment: https://johnoleksowicz.com/retrieve-environment-codeception-helper/ got my answer, praise the internet.